# SSRS: Report timing out after 2 mins

Tags: reporting-services, ssms, ssrs-2016

I'm having issues with one of my reports timing out when certain parameters are passed to it. This seems to happen when the execution of the stored procedure (that builds the dataset for the report) runs over 2 mins.

I have ran the query within SSMS and the query runs and finishes in 2 mins 5 seconds.

I have read up on numerous ways on trying to increase this time out value:

- Updating the report on the web portal to run indefinitely.
- Updating the remote query timeout for the db instance (set to 600s)
- Updating DatabaseQueryTimeout in rsreportserver.config (set to 360s)
- Updated Httpruntime, executionTimeout property in web.config (set to 9000s)

Moving back through the chain I have found that the issue persists when running the report directly from the SSRS web portal.

When you inspect the console on the site, I get the following:
[image: SSRS Timeout error]

Funnily enough if i hit view report again after hitting this error the report is correctly generated. guessing this is because the query data was cached?

Was wondering if anyone has experienced this and would be able to give me guidance on a setting / configuration which would stop the timeout.

The version of SSRS is 2016

Comment: I suggest to increase the speed of the stored procedure, as I don't think that your users have a timeout value that can be increased.

Comment: This might have to be the solution if i can't increase the timeout. The query is computationally expensive as it has to apply a lot of logic when processing the data. It suffers from parameter sniffing as well due to the large assortment of parameters the report can have.  Might look into using data warehousing to pre-run the logic into a table the query can use before running the report. Thanks for the heads up .